Create a registration screen in dart code
write a code in dart language to create an registration screen
after clicking on Create an acount these details should appear Name Phone number Email DOB Gender User name Password: character special character numerical value Confirm password
after clicking on login these details should appear Email Password logged in successfully Forget Password: recover from phone number or email id
after clicking on Continue with google Email ID: options Password Vertification code logged in successfully
now create the registration page code in dart language by following the main dart and login page code
after clicking on Create an acount these details should appear Name Phone number Email DOB Gender User name Password: character special character numerical value Confirm password
after clicking on login these details should appear Email Password logged in successfully Forget Password: recover from phone number or email id
after clicking on Continue with google Email ID: options Password Vertification code logged in successfully
now create the registration page code in dart language by following the main dart and login page code

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This seems to be a home assignment for an interview or a classroom.   If so, please don't use SO to cheat.  It's ok to show some code and ask specific questions, but we're not doing your homework for you.
